# In VHDL, Can I use signal'event if signal is not a clock?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to clean up my VHDL code. I have a signal that is NOT a clk.

Can I write an event change monitor like the following and how do I get it to compile so it can be synthesized? (see code) I have tried several permutations but I cannot get it to compile. Will signal'event compile if signal is not a CLK and if so, how is it done? I see on the web and other literature that it can be done but all examples I see show CLK'event.

```
signal cntr: unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

...
process(CLK):
begin

IF rising_edge(CLK) THEN
    if (cntr'event) then
        do something;
    end if;
or...
    if(cntr(0)'event) then
        do something;
    end if;
END IF;
end process;
```

I get the following and others
: can't synthesize condition that contains an isolated 'EVENT predefined attribute

Comment: What do you expect? a 'event occurs whenever a signal changes. While its perfectly valid VHDL, in a real circuit, that only really applies to a clock.

Comment: I don't what you are trying to do but *"..clean up my VHDL code"* together with *using cntr(0) as edge* does not sound good. A good HDL design has one clock and uses the edge of that only. It is a common flaw I see again and again with inexperienced HDL designer to want to use different edges all over the place **Don't** Unless you design is special (e.g. Clock Domain Crossing) you should run it all from one clock.

Comment: This appears off topic and VHDL is not an object oriented programming language, it's a Hardware Description Language (the [tag:events] tag is not appropriate). Consider asking how to describe an event in hardware which may depend on what the "do something" is, ask a specific question.

Comment: From one of your previous questions your a Quartus user, a tool suite that expects a certain hardware expertise for those providing RTL design specifications. A historically good reference would be IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) which describes non high level synthesis eligible VHDL constructs.

Comment: Here is my issue, I have a fifo input and I added a counter to count the data points from the fifo. The first 10 or so data inputs are header/setup values. After the first 10 data points, all data is processed in the same routine. If no data arrives after a few seconds, The FPGA needs to refresh the header values.  My hope was to then look at the clock_counter and if after a few seconds or clock_counter = 300000000, I would reset the the data_counter.

Comment: In your question. Your comment doesn't draw an adequate word picture (show specifics). You could show your existing code and synthesis error messages. The sticky bit might be where restructuring is involved. Can you add a bit to the FIFO data width flagging header or data? Comments that are no longer applicable can be flagged for removal. As this question stands your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're focused on your attempted solution that doesn't gracefully become hardware.

Comment: I had a more comprehensive comment but SO constrained me by time and size.

Comment: VHDL has way more language elements than synthesis software can build hardware from. When writing VHDL for FPGAs (hardware is already on silicon), you are even more restricted as you can only synthesise a subset of circuits the hardware is designed for (i.e. you can't design a circuit the hardware has no suitable building blocks available). Read (and strictly follow) the _recommended design practices_ chapter in your Quartus II Handbook.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I looked at that section in the handbook. I got so caught up in VHDL, I forgot that I was limited to my particular FPGA type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rising_edge(CLK)` is already an event, making your design synchronous, which is good. As said in comments, only clock signals should use that.
Looking at another even at that time doesn't make sense in synchronous designs, as the 2 signals won't change exactly at the same time, creating a race condition. Or actually a clock within a clock, and the synthesis error...
It may work in simulation, but don't rely on that fact.
The normal way to program in HDL languages is to save the previous value of the signal, on the same clock (for example `cntr_d <= cntr`) and to compare with that previous value. That allows to find if the signal went up (previously at 0, currently at 1), went down, changed (is different)...
And that method is perfectly fine for synthesis!

Comment: Thank you, I hit on your method late last night. It went something like this inside a process on a clk edge..(if a /= b;) ... do something... (a<= b;)...(end if;)...(end process;)